# Does function with empty body take place in memory in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have just come across this question, and i think the answer should be yes but not sure

Comment: Can you included an code example in your question? This helps a lot with people's ability to answer questions effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

JavaScript interpreters will either need to create a new object representing the function or at least a reference to a singleton instance of the identity function, both of which consume memory.